# How to get the last row value in pandas through dataframe.get_value()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I follow this instruction https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-get_value/ and know how to get the value from a dateframe data in pandas:

```
df.get_value(10, 'Salary')
```

My question is how to get the value of 'Salary' in the last row?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First of all I would advise against using get_value since it is/will be deprecated. (see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.get_value.html )

There are a couple of solutions:

```
df['Salary'].iloc[-1]
df.Salary.iloc[-1]
```

are synonymous. Iloc is the way to retrieve items in a pandas df by their index.

```
df['Salary'].values[-1]
```

creates a list of the Salary column and returns the last items

```
df['Salary'].tail(1)
df.Salary.tail(1)
```

returns the last row of the salary column.

Which of the solutions is best, depends on the context and your personal preference.

Answer (score 4):

This will select salary in the last row.

```
df['Salary'][-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

In pandas there exists a tail function:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['alligator', 'bee', 'falcon', 'lion',
                   'monkey', 'parrot', 'shark', 'whale', 'zebra']})

>>> df.tail(1)
    animal
8   zebra
```

(See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html)

---

Or you could simply do:

```
>>>df[-1:]
    animal
8   zebra
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`take`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.take.html):

```
df['Salary'].take([-1])
```